# Set response headers in CQ5/AEM

Tags: aem

We need to set below response headers in CQ5/AEM based application.

**Http Header: Frame options    Set X-Frame-Options: SAME ORIGIN
Http Header: Strict Transport Security  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload**

I have done like these changes in my prior application using servlet filter to intercept the request. Similarly I tried to use the SlingFilter for this application. However it seems to be called many times for each request (when it download js,css,json files etc). Please see below code snippet,

```
@SlingFilter(scope = SlingFilterScope.COMPONENT, order = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
@Properties({

    @Property(name="pattern",value="/soni/template/", propertyPrivate=false) 
})
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {

                HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;        
                httpResponse.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains");
                filterChain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
                httpResponse.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

        } catch (Exception e) {                 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

    }
```

Is this the right way to do it in CQ5/AEM? How do I restrict this to once per page request?
or is there better way to do it like configuration at dispatcher etc?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this from the Apache/Dispatcher layer?

Comment: Looking at that option as well, that was part of my question. I have asked the admins at my company to look into it. I am new to CQ5/AEM. I think we can do as per below link,              https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Specifying the HTTP Headers to Pass Through - /clientheaders                                                         Do you have any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: Filter will intercept every HTTP request i.e. html, js, css, images etc which is why it is being called multiple times as you've observed. If I have to infer from the name of the headers in the code snippet, these appear to be related to security. Is there a reason why you don't want these headers for all requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the *Component* scope, this filter is called every time you include a component, which is not your intention.

Please use *request* scope:

```
scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST
```

Refer to this page:
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html

Comment: I tried SlingFilterScope.REQUEST. Its the same issue...filter is called for json,.png,.gif....